# Django + Ajax - rendering small part of large data on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a Django app rendering a large table. My global purpose is to render only a small fraction of table, say, 10-20 records, on page load so that the user does not wait years, and then asynchronously upload the rest of the table in background ajax call making the rows invisible. Then, as the user scrolls down, the rows consecutively show up.

I have drafted a preliminary architecture, but this doesn't seem to me the cleanest way to do this.

What I plan to do as for now can be described the following way:

**Step 1.** Render the first 10 rows by doing this:

```
view get_first_10_rows(request):
    qs = some_orm_query[:10]
    return render_to_response('order_scheduler/orders.html',
                              'qs':qs},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Step 2.** Get json-analogue of the queryset in a jquery function after the page has been fully rendered appending it to the table in 'display:none' mode:

View:

```
 view get_entire_rows(request):
        qs = some_orm_query.all()
        return render_to_response('order_scheduler/orders.html',
                                  'qs':qs},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Jquery/AJAX

```
$(function () {
     $.get(..., function(json_result){
        // loop through json
        // append rows to the table and apply 'display:none'
        //
     }); 
});
```

**Step 3.**

Write a jquery function that shows hidden rows as the user scrolls down the page.

---

There are two concerns with this. First, if the table in question is rendered using Django formsets, then I have no idea how to render the table in jquery via json. And the second, I will have to write a lot of js script that clones the code that I have already written in Django template for cycle. This means that every time I change something in template, I have to revise my js code. 
I am sure there's a cleaner and more straightforward way to do this.

Alternatively, I could give up Django templates, and write the table code purely in js. The downside of this approach seems the sacrifice of Django formsets that are pretty much valuable for making the table cells editable and the functionality of saving user updates to the DB. 
Could anyone give me a hint how to do this ? Even a high-level recommendation or a key-word should be appreciated. I don't know where to start from and what to google.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load data asynchronously, you can use infinite [scrolling with Django and some Javascript](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html) as explained by Vitor Freitas:

In `models.py` :

> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Article(models.Model):
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
>     body = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
>     date = models.DateTimeField()
>     author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
> ```

in `views.py`  :

> ```
> from django.views.generic.list import ListView
> from .models import Article
>
> class ArticlesView(ListView):
>     model = Article
>     paginate_by = 10 # where you define the 10 records you want the user to initially see
>     context_object_name = 'articles'
>     template_name = 'blog/articles.html'
> ```
>
> and `urls.py`:
>
> ```
> from .views import ArticlesView
> .
> .
> .
> url(r'^articles$', ArticlesView.as_view(), name='articles'),
> ```

And then in the template `articles.html`:

> ```
> <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
> <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
> <script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
>
> <div class="infinite-container">
>     {% for article in articles %}
>       <div class="infinite-item">
>         <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>
>         <p>
>           <small>{{ article.author }} / {{ article.date }}</small>
>         </p>
>         <p>{{ article.body|truncatechars:100 }}</p>
>       </div>
>     {% endfor %}
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
>     Loading...
>   </div>
>
>   {% if page_obj.has_next %}
>     <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ articles.next_page_number }}">More</a>
>   {% endif %}
>
>   <script>
>     var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
>       element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
>       onBeforePageLoad: function () {
>         $('.loading').show();
>       },
>       onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
>         $('.loading').hide();
>       }
>     });
>   </script>
> ```